# Understanding AppEngine _ah/stats result

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have this result in App Stats for AppEngine, and I can't work it out, it looks like each part performs ok, but there is a huge gap. Any Ideas?

[image: AppStat Result]

Context:
It's a registration system, it checks if the username/email already exists, send an email to the user, puts the data into the database.

Comment: Give us some context bout what you are testing.

Comment: Done, any more info, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appstats only shows the timing of the GAE API/RPC calls.  It's quite possible that all the time is spent in your code, or another library you use that isn't waiting for GAE RPC calls.  You have to analyse performance of that code on your own.

Comment: Thanks, I did some crude time testing and indeed it was some other code I had running!